# Wire up StructureMap with generic open type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

How would I wire up StructureMap with the following:

```
public Interface IRepository<T, TIdentity>{}
public abstract class Repository<T, TIdentity> : IRepository<T, TIdentity>, other interfaces
```

I have many concrete implementations of Repository and need StructureMap to wire them up automatically.

```
public class JournalRepository : Repository<Journal,int>{}
public class UsersRepository : Repository<Users,int>{}
public class AccountGroupsRepository : Repository<Accounts,string>{}
```

etc.

I've tried:

```
 x.ForRequestedType(typeof(IRepository<,>))
.TheDefaultIsConcreteType(typeof(Repository<,>));
```

but I just get StructureMap Exception Code:  25 (with no explanation).

Is this at all possible?

Many thanks
Jeremy

Comment: Jeremy, add a programming language tag, I'd do it for you but I'm bad at guessing ;) This will increase visibilty for your question and the number of answers!

Comment: You mean like C#? i hadnt' realized that was neccessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is built in support for this using:

```
Scan(assemblyScanner =>
             {
                 assemblyScanner.TheCallingAssembly();
                 assemblyScanner.AddAllTypesOf(typeof (IRepository<>));
                 assemblyScanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(
                    typeof(IRepository<>));
             });
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks very much - I just wish I could find the documentation for StructureMap

Comment: The docs are available at http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/index.html
otherwise the google group is usually most helpful http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users?hl=en